# Ubuntu newby question on mounting a networked drive so it's visible in Crashplan

Tags: networking, mount, hard-drive, samba

I have an old MacBook Pro that I used to run Crashplan. I've got a 2TB HDD attached to a Raspberry Pi that I use as a NAS. The MacBook could see the drive no problem and it was visible in Crashplan.

The MBP is now too old to run OSX properly so I've installed Ubuntu and it seems way more stable.

In Files I can see the networked drive as smb://raspberrypi.local/thedrive/ and I've mounted it by right-clicking and choosing 'mount' by I can't find it when trying to add the drive within Crashplan - it doesn't show up in /media or /mnt.

What do I need to do to make it visible?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the Crashplan people.

Comment: You may want to mount the smb share using `fstab` at the system start. See [questions and answers on this topic](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mount+fstab+smb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what crashplan is but `smb://raspberrypi.local/thedrive/` will mount to:

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=raspberrypi.local,share=thedrive
```

Where $UID is your user id number - usually 1000.

Just open a terminal and run:

```
ls -l /run/user/$UID/gvfs
```

**EDIT**: **You might do better with a cifs mount:**

Create a mount point - example:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/thedrive
```

Then do a temporary mount:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //raspberrypi.local/thedrive /mnt/thedrive -o username=XXXX,password=YYYY,uid=1000
```

Replace XXXX and YYYY with the credentials the pi is expecting and change 1000 to your real uid number - run `id` in a terminal if you don't know.

**EDIT2: To make it persistent add the following to fstab:**

```
//raspberrypi.local/thedrive /mnt/thedrive cifs username=XXXX,password=YYYY,uid=1000 0 0
```

A variation of that line that makes it mount when the mount point is accessed would look like this:

```
//raspberrypi.local/thedrive /mnt/thedrive cifs username=XXXX,password=YYYY,uid=1000,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

This one is useful if your system tries to access the pi before the network stack is fully operational.

Comment: Thanks - I can navigate to it through Files but it's not visible from within Crashplan (backup software) - gvfs appears as a file rather than a folder. On Mac, mounted drives would appear as a separate folder but I can't see the mount at all.

Comment: Please see my EDIT above to see if a cifs mount resolves this issue.

Comment: That's perfect! will it be persistent or do I need to add it to fstab?

Comment: Added EDIT2 for fstab syntax.

Comment: Absolutely perfect - thank you!